# Data are not inserted in mongodb, it gives could not get any response error in postman

Tags: mean-stack

I build the project using the mean stack. I insert record using postman but I get one error, I try to resolve much time but not to find where is a mistake.

[Postman error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HR1EA.png)

This is models user.js file.which is shows userSchema details.
**Models -> user.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
var config = require('../config/database');

// User Schema

var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports.getUserById = function(id, callback){
    User.findById(id, callback);
}

module.exports.getUserByUsername = function(username, callback){
    var query = {username: username}
    User.findOne(query, callback);
}

module.exports.addUser = function(newUser, callback){
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
        bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
            if(err) throw err; 
            newUSer.password = hash;
            newUser.save(callback);
        });
    });
}
```

This is Routes user.js file. here router of register displays, also define add user status results that can be shown if postman value is inserted in mongo then successfully another wise unsuccessfull message.
**Routes -> users.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var password = require('passport');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

var User = require('../models/user');

// Register
router.post('/register', function(req, res, next){
    let newUser = new User({
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password
    });

    User.addUser(newUser, (err, user) => {
        if(err){
            res.json({success: false, msg:'Failed to Register User'});
        } else {
            res.json({success: true, msg:'User Registered'});
        }
    });
});

// Authenticate
router.post('/authenticate', function(req, res, next){
    res.send('Authenticate');
});


// Profile
router.get('/profile', function(req, res, next){
    res.send('Profile');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: POSTMAN Error:- Could not get any response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending the request wrongly from Postman. You should not use x-www-form-urlencoded. Use the Raw option at send it as a json object, like this:

```
{
    "name": "Mark Melton",
    "email": "xyz@gmail.com",
    "username": "shuta",
    "password": "Sunala123"
}
```

This is how it will work, because in your routes, you are using req.body...